# Turtle: Prompting for input, without a trailing newline

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I'm writing a console application that needs to prompt the user for several things. I'm using the [turtle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0) library.

My function looks like this:

```
askInput :: IO (Maybe Text)
askInput = do
    echo "Input something: "
    s <- readline
    return s
```

But `echo` is [implemented](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.0.0/docs/src/Turtle-Prelude.html#echo) using `putStrLn` and as a result, will print its argument with a trailing newline.

Is there an input function in the turtle library similar to Python's `raw_input`, that combines prompting followed by reading the user input?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can import from the [`text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text) package and use many functions which aren't exported from `turtle`. In this case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import qualified Data.Text.IO as Text

main = Text.putStr "Input something: " -- doesn't print newline
```

Answer (score 2):

I also want to mention that `turtle` has a newly added `printf` function which outputs a formatted string without the trailing newline, so another solution is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Turtle

main = printf "Input something: "
```